# How remove one element with a score in Redis?

Tags: redis, node-redis

How to remove one element in sorted set by score in Redis?
If I need to remove element with a score timestamp `1417727661` will be right?

```
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE key 1417727661
```

Or `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE key 1417727661 1417727661`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the full documentation of that call:

http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore

It looks like for your case, `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE key 1417727661 1417727661` is correct. Remember that the ranges are inclusive by default. You can make them exclusive by following the syntax on this page:

http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore

`ZREMRANGEBYSCORE key 1417727661 (1417727662`

means scores greater than or equal to `1417727661` but less than `1417727662`

Comment: In my example will be delete note only strong equal  1417727662?

Comment: Some notes does not delete, I get them score and try delete like as `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE key 1417727661 1417727661`

Comment: Just making sure, but you are using the right `key` right? Example:
`ZADD **myzset** 1 "one"` should be removed by
`ZREMRANGEBYSCORE **myzset** 1 1`

Comment: Dont understand your comment. I specifed a corect key and timestamp score. Why does redis delete element sometimes not?

Comment: maybe multi-threading, and another thread already removed it?

Comment: I dont knew, how I can check it? I send request by AJAX and simply to call methos `DeleteRedisEvent`

Comment: This is my code PHP: `$key = $this->_key('User', $userID);
        return $this->redis->zRemRangeByScore($key, $score, $score);`